# Infinite series with a binomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'd like to know, is there any place where I can find the proof of this?
[image]

in some radius of convergence?

Comment: that's Catalan numbers generating function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $f(t) = (1-4t)^{-1/2}$ and develop the Taylor series. It is seen that
\begin{align}
f(t) &= (1-4t)^{-1/2} \\
f'(t) &= 2 (1-4t)^{-3/2} \\
f''(t) &= 12 (1-4t)^{-5/2} \\
\cdots &= \cdots 
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
f(t) &= 1 + 2 t + 6 t^{2} + \cdots \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, t^{n}
\end{align}
Now let $t = p q x^{2}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} (pq x^{2})^{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4 pq x^{2}}}.
\end{align}